# For each user return rows where user bought same item n times within 10 minutes in MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb

MariaDB version 10.2.21

I have a table that looks like:

```
    user_id  item_id      start_time            end_time
1    412374   2349    2020-01-01 04:01:44     2020-01-01 04:01:51
2    271274   2519    2020-01-01 04:02:41     2020-01-01 04:03:33
3    271274   2519    2020-01-01 04:05:37     2020-01-01 04:06:14
4    349729   6979    2020-01-01 04:10:44     2020-01-01 04:10:49
5    79011    2785    2020-01-01 04:54:38     2020-01-01 04:55:06
6    68486    5395    2020-01-01 05:39:23     2020-01-01 05:40:03
7    68486    5395    2020-01-01 05:55:23     2020-01-01 05:59:03
```

- Within 10 minutes => row 2's end_time and row 3's start_time is within 10 minutes. Even though row 1 end_time and row 2 start_time are within 10 minutes I do not want it since they are different user.
- row 6,7: user_id is the same and bought same item however row 6 end_time ~ row 7 start_time is over 10 minutes therefore I do not want them.

desired table after filter:

```
    user_id  item_id      start_time            end_time
1    271274   2519    2020-01-01 04:02:41     2020-01-01 04:03:33
2    271274   2519    2020-01-01 04:05:37     2020-01-01 04:06:14
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 5.8? Are you sure? Do you mean 8.0.X? You need extra clarity as to what you're trying to eliminate and the exact criteria for this.

Comment: When I run SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%"; it tells me that version is 10.2.21-MariaDB... Are they compatible with each other?

Comment: 5.8 never really existed as a release so its hard to gauge its compatibility. MySQL and MariaDB have some compatibility, however for a question its very helpful if the real version is shown.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the feed back I've updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `EXISTS` query to check for a transaction on the same `user_id` and `item_id` within a 10 minute period:

```
SELECT *
FROM sales s1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM sales s2
              WHERE s2.id != s1.id
                AND s2.user_id = s1.user_id
                AND s2.item_id = s1.item_id
                AND (s2.start_time BETWEEN s1.end_time AND s1.end_time + INTERVAL 10 MINUTE
                  OR s1.start_time BETWEEN s2.end_time AND s2.end_time + INTERVAL 10 MINUTE
                    )
              )
ORDER BY id
```

Output:

```
id  user_id     item_id     start_time              end_time
2   271274      2519        2020-01-01 04:02:41     2020-01-01 04:03:33
3   271274      2519        2020-01-01 04:05:37     2020-01-01 04:06:14
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=ac9e7e54f586a432b9c19d377f465dc6)

Comment: hey, I just want to make things clear. Reason for "OR" inside where clause in subquery which compares s2.start_time with s1's end_times then s1.start_time with s2's end_time is because s2.start_time with s1's end_times would not contain s2_start_time itself right?

Comment: @Ambleu it's because you don't know which of `s1` or `s2` occurs first, so you have to compare both `end_time` values with both `start_time` values. Otherwise you would only get one of the rows in the output.

Comment: Thanks Nick for answering. I'm still quite confused isn't query comparing s1 row to all s2 where there id do not match?

Comment: @Ambleu that's right, and then the two time comparisons check whether either s1's start time is within 10 minutes of s2's end time, or whether s2's start time is within 10 minutes of s1's end time.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different form of output side by side rather than list:

```
  SELECT t1.*, t2.*
  FROM tbl t1
  JOIN tbl t2
     ON t1.id!=t2.id
        AND t1.user_id = t2.user_id
        AND t1.item_id = t2.item_id
        AND (t1.start_time BETWEEN t2.start_time - INTERVAL 10 MINUTES AND t2.end_time + INTERVAL 10 MINUTES
            OR t1.end_time BETWEEN t2.start_time - INTERVAL 10 MINUTES AND t2.end_time + INTERVAL 10 MINUTES)
```